# Big O notation for n/2 in while-loop

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm new to data structure and the likes of it.

I would like to ask a question, how do we determine the Big-O notation value of this process:

```
while(n%2==0){
   console.log(2);
   n=n/2;
}
```

What is the Big-O notation? Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `n` odd then the loop is not executed. If `n` is even then it takes  `log2n` (*i.e.,* log of base 2) iterations until the loop stops. It is `log2n`  because `n` gets decrement to half each loop iterations (`i.e.,` `n=n/2;`).

Assuming that `console.log(2);` takes `c` time the overall complexity would be `O(logn)`.